# Assigning text to buttons Via methods

Tags: c#

I'm messing around trying to make a tictactoe game and am wondering how to use this method I created to alter the text of a button.

```
private void Click()
{
    if (player1 == true)
    {
        player1 = false;
        player2 = true;

        this.Text = "X";
    }
    if (player2 == true)
    {
        player1 = true;
        player2 = false;

        this.Text = "O";
    }
} 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Click();
}
```

So I want to be able to change the text of the buttons, I found out that this relates to the actual form. I couldn't find any ways to assign the text to different buttons only if you are specific. Cheeeeers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" is your form. You need to assign your text to button.Text.
Since your are writing a tic-tac-toe you could use the same event for all buttons :)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var button = (Button) sender;
     button.Text = "X";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the button1 as a parameter to your click event, like:

```
private void Click(Control control) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text)) {
        // invalid button clicked (has already x or o)
        return;
    }
    control.Text = player1 ? 'X' : 'O';
    player1 = !player1;
    player2 = !player2;
}
```

and then use the click event as:

```
private void GeneralButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Click(sender as Control);
}
```

after which you could attach all buttons to this GeneralButtonHandler

and if you need more ideas for the game, you could find a javascript implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/oLyvwdph/)